# Laravel and Vue: My layout blade loads a script that my components can't see

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I load up my app.js bundle in my layout.blade.php and I am also running this in my layout.blade.php under the  section:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({
        appId   : '{{ fb_app_id() }}',
        xfbml   : true,
        version : '{{ fb_api_version() }}'
    });
};
```

but it seems my Vue components don't have access to it so I have to run it when the component mounts as well.  Do

Answer (score 0):

you need to call your script before app.js file like this

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

FB.init({
    appId   : '{{ fb_app_id() }}',
    xfbml   : true,
    version : '{{ fb_api_version() }}'
});
};
</script>
```

```
<script src="your path to app.js file"></script>
```